# how to connect elasticache redis cluster to fastapi in ecs fargate when using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, terraform, amazon-elasticache

My fastapi task is in ecs fargate which is set in private subnet.
and I'm going to use elasticache redis cluster to save refresh token.
so I think I need connect by using redis config() in fastapi to connect redis.

this is my redis config function in fastapi.

```py
    def redis_config() :
    try:
        REDIS_HOST = str = "master.redis-cluster.r8ktvp.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379"
        rd = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST)

    except:
        print("redis connection failure")
    return rd
```

and I set the environment variables in ecs task definition.

```
REDIS_ENDPOINT="master.redis-cluster.r8ktvp.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com"
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

and this is my terraform code.

```
resource "aws_elasticache_subnet_group" "redis_subnet_group" {
  name = "iol-redis-cache"
  subnet_ids = ["${aws_subnet.redis_subnet.0.id}"]
}



resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "redis_cluster" {
  replication_group_id          = "redis-cluster"

  availability_zones            = ["ap-northeast-2a"]
  engine                        = "redis"
  engine_version                = "7.0"
  at_rest_encryption_enabled    = true
  transit_encryption_enabled    = true
  automatic_failover_enabled    = false
  node_type                     = "cache.t2.small"
  num_cache_clusters            = 1
  parameter_group_name          = "default.redis7"
  port                          = 6379
  subnet_group_name             = aws_elasticache_subnet_group.redis_subnet_group.name
  security_group_ids            = [aws_security_group.redis.id]
  replication_group_description = "Redis cluster for caching storage (has automatic eviction)"

  log_delivery_configuration {
    destination      = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log-group.id
    destination_type = "cloudwatch-logs"
    log_format       = "json"
    log_type         = "engine-log"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["number_cache_clusters"]
  }
}
```

when I check the cloudwatch log.
I got this error:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to master.redis-cluster.r8ktvp.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379:6379. Name or service not known.
```

I think `~.amazonaws.com:6379:6379` this is not correct so I tried revise redis host in redis config many times LIKE THIS: master.redis-cluster.r8ktvp.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com BUT when I tried this, there is no log and occurs time out.

security group is.. I just OPEN 6379 PORT.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "redis" {
  name = "redis-security-group"
  description = "ALLOWS INBOUND ACCESS FROM ECS ONLY"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id

  ingress {
    protocol = "tcp"
    from_port = "6379"
    to_port = "6379"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.fastapi_task.id]
  }
  egress {
    protocol = "-1"
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

and this is my ecs task definition resource.
I will omit the environment variables of jwt and postgres!

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "fastapi" {
  family                   = "fastapi"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = 1024
  memory                   = 4096
  execution_role_arn  ="${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn}"
  task_role_arn            = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.arn}"
  depends_on = [aws_db_instance.postgres]
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
    "image": "7xxx.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/repo-backend:651ab219c10f78394f8d594bf505ae574a755139",
    "cpu": 1024,
    "memory": 4096,
    "name": "fastapi",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ],
    "environment": [
      {
        "name" : "REDIS_ENDPOINT",
        "value" : "${var.REDIS_ENDPOINT}"
      },
      {
        "name" : "REDIS_PORT",
        "name" : "${var.REDIS_PORT}"
      }
    ]
  }
]
DEFINITION
}
```

I have no idea.. how to fix it??
thank you for reading!:D

Comment: Are you sure that's all the code you have? It seems you have omitted the task definition part.

Comment: Great. And are the Redis terraform code and the code for ECS task in the same root module or not?

Comment: no, not same root module. I just two of them are in same vpc. but in different subnet! I've never used module in terraform code this time..

Comment: I think the issue here is how you are using the REDIS_HOST variable. Not sure about the Python library, but it might be that if you do not specify a `port` explicitly it uses 6379 by default. So either do something like `rd = redis.Redis(host="master.redis-cluster.r8ktvp.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com", port=6379)`, or use the endpoint and port from the environment variables, but I guess you would also have to use the `os` library for that to work.

Comment: It is appending the port number to the host twice. You should remove the port from your `REDIS_HOST` variable. It's also weird that you are hard-coding the `REDIS_HOST` value instead of using the environment variables you took the time to setup.

Comment: @MarkoE @Mark B  thank you! I changed it like you guys said! There was also a port problem, but since `ssl=true` is set in redis config, it works fine!!!!